# 我爱去饭店吃饭。我想去饭店吃米饭，可是我觉得我会去家吃苹果: Does this make grammatical sense?

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

I am just practicing writing. Does this make sense?

我饿死了！我爱去饭店吃饭。我想去饭店吃米饭，可是我觉得我会去家吃苹果。

Comment: 去家 should be 回家 (go home)  unless it is "去 someone's 家"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tang Ho's suggestion is OK but 飯店 usually means hotel (especially in Taiwan), so do you really mean the following?

> I am so hungry! I want to go to hotel to have a meal, but I think I will go back home and eat an apple.

If you mean you want to go to a **restaurant**, use 餐廳/餐館 instead:

> 我餓死了！我想去餐館吃飯，可是我覺得我會回家吃蘋果。

Also, eating apples as an alternative to having a meal in a restaurant or hotel is OK but not good, because if you are so hungry, eating 1 or 2 apples obviously is not enough. Do you want to cook some noodles or pastas?

> 我餓死了！我想去餐館吃飯，可是我覺得我會回家煮麵吃。

Answer (score 1):

> 我饿死了！ - I am so hungry (O)
>
> 我饿死了！ 我爱去饭店吃饭 - I am very hungry! I love to go to restaurant to have a meal (X)
>
> *The two clauses do not seem to be related*

~

> 我饿死了！我想去饭店吃饭 - I am very hungry, I want to go to restaurant to have a meal (O)
>
> The first part is the cause/ reason and the second part is the result/reaction. The two clauses are related

~

> 我饿死了！我想去饭店吃饭，可是我觉得我会**回**家吃苹果。(O)

*米饭 specifically means 'cooked rice', 吃米饭 in this sentence should be changed to '吃饭' (having meal)*

*去家 should be 回家 (go home) unless it is "去 someone's 家"*